# vhdl expression has 2 elements, but must have 3 elements

Tags: vhdl

Quartus keeps telling me that "expression has 2 elements, but must have 3 elements" on the "result:= to_unsigned(1, 1) + unsigned(X) + unsigned(Y);" line. 
below is my code for building a CLA

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity cla2 is
port(
    X, Y : in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
    Cin : in std_logic;
    S, BP, BG  : out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
    Cout : out  std_logic
    );
end cla2;

architecture Behavior of cla2 is 

begin 

process(X, Y, Cin)
    variable result : unsigned (2 downto 0);

begin
    if(Cin = '1') then
    result:= to_unsigned(1, 1) + unsigned(X) + unsigned(Y);
    else 
    result:= unsigned(X) + unsigned(Y);
    end if;
    S<= std_logic_vector(result(1 downto 0));
    Cout<= result(2);
    BP<=X or Y;
    BG<=X and Y;
end process;
end Behavior;
```

Answer (score 4):

The complete error message if it were shown would be along the lines of

> Error (10344): VHDL expression error at cla2.vhd(23): expression has 2 elements, but must have 3 elements

varying by the actual file name and assuming you've displayed the entire file.

The 23th line is:

```
    result:= to_unsigned(1, 1) + unsigned(X) + unsigned(Y);
```

where we see an expression on the right hand side of the assignment consisting of adding a one bit 1 and X and Y together after type conversion to type unsigned.

If we look at the declarations

```
    X, Y : in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
```

and

```
    variable result : unsigned (2 downto 0);
```

we see the result has 3 elements while the expression has 2. (See package numeric_std in library IEEE, "+"[unsigned, unsigned return unsigned] returns a value of the length of the longest operand.

There's a requirement that the expression on the right hand side has an element for every element of the target `result`. See IEEE Std 1076-2008 10.6 Variable assignment statement, 10.6.2.2 Composite variable assignments:

> If the target of an assignment statement is a name denoting a composite variable (including a slice), the value assigned to the target is implicitly converted to the subtype of the composite variable; the result of this subtype conversion becomes the new value of the composite variable.
>
> This means that the new value of each element of the composite variable is specified by the matching element (see 9.2.3) in the corresponding composite value obtained by evaluation of the expression. The subtype conversion checks that for each element of the composite variable there is a matching element in the composite value, and vice versa. An error occurs if this check fails.

which tells us it's an error if both sides of the variable assignment don't have the same number of elements.

We can fix that:

```
    result:= to_unsigned(1, 3) + unsigned(X) + unsigned(Y);
```

by changing the left operand of the first "+" width, and that clears this error.

BUT, the other assignment has the same problem on line 25:

```
    result:= unsigned(X) + unsigned(Y);
```

And that needs to be fixed.

Fixing that is easy. We could use Resize on an operand or use the higher precedence concatenation operator "&" to imply specify the expression width:

```
    result:= unsigned('0' & X) + unsigned(Y);
```

The left most expression defines the result width.

This isn't about synthesis it's about VHDL semantics you can demonstrate with simulation where these errors would also be reported.